# Querying for multiple XML attributes in the same XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have XML documents that I am querying. From the example XML below, `$Match = TRUE` when a USER has a Password, AND STATUS = "a" and ACTION = "h". These are all in the same XML.

```xml
<BusinessUnitList>
  <User id="1407210" loginName="1407210" password="Password1" statusCode="a">


<WorkStatusList>
  <WorkStatus start="2016-10-13" status="a" action="h" />
```

I can query for one or the other attribute:

```
$Match = (gc "c:\file.xml | Select-Xml -XPATH "//User" | select -ExpandProperty node | where {$_.password})
$Match2 = (gc "c:\file.xml | Select-Xml -XPATH "//WorkStatus" | select -ExpandProperty node | where {$_.status -eq "a" -and $_.action -eq "h"}
```

But I don't know how to combine the two, so that the condition is only TRUE when all three values exist and/or present.

I have tried combining the script with `-and`, but to no avail.

```
$Match = (gc "c:\file.xml | Select-Xml -XPath "//User" | select -ExpandProperty node | where {$_.password}) -and
         (gc "c:\file.xml | Select-Xml -XPath "//WorkStatus" | select -ExpandProperty node | where {$_.status -eq "a" -and $_.action -eq "h"})
```

Comment: `$Match` will be true if the document contains a `User` node that contains a `password` attribute. `$Match2` will be true if the document contains a `WorkStatus` node with attribute `status="a"` and `action="h"`. Are you trying to flag any document that contains at least one such `User` node and at least one such `WorkStatus` node?

Comment: Please clarify the hierarchy in your XML sample. Is `<WorkStatusList>` a child node of `<User>`? A child node of `<BusinessUnitList>`? On the same hierarchy level as `<BusinessUnitList>`?

Comment: Both conditions have to match, ie, User and WorkStatus values that meet certain values. There are many combinations of User and WorkStatus, so I'm filtering out the ones that do not interest me.

Comment: That does not answer my question. XML is a hierarchical data format. The answer you just accepted will match if there is any `<User>` with a `password` attribute (even an empty one) and any `<WorkStatus>` with attributes `status='a'` and `action='h'`. If that's what you're looking for: fine. But if the file contains more than one `<User>` and/or `<WorkStatus>` node and you're looking for a more specific match you need to provide more information about your XML structure. Is it `<User><WorkStatus/></User>`? `<BusinessUnitList><User/></WorkStatus/></BusinessUnitList>`? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to read the document into an `XML` object to start. That way you don't have to iterate the file multiple times. Then, you can use an XPath expression inside of the `SelectNodes()` function. Simply `-and` the two different `SelectNode()` calls, and you get your result. Like so:

```
$xml = [XML] (gc c:\file.xml)
$Match = $xml.SelectNodes("//WorkStatus[@status='a'and @action='h']").Count -gt 0 -and $xml.SelectNodes("//User[@password]").Count -gt 0
```

Comment: Super thanks - I have since read other answers elsewhere with similar answers.